# jquery show and hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a javascript code that when a link is clicked, it can show and hide divisions of the page.

```
function shoh(id) { 

    if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6
        if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == "none"){
            $(id).fadeIn();     
        } else {
            $(id).hide();   
        }   
    } else { 
        if (document.layers) {  
            if (document.id.display == "none"){
                document.id.display = 'block';
            } else {
                document.id.display = 'none';
            }
        } else {
            if (document.all.id.style.visibility == "none"){
                document.all.id.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                document.all.id.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

however it now doesn't work when i added the jquery fadeIn and hide instead of using the document.getElementByid method. why?

Comment: Have you added the jQuery library to load with the page?

Comment: Why are you using this horrible compatibility code from 2000 in 2013? You would not even need jQuery here, *all* browsers support `getElementById` today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to select an element by id with jQuery, you have to use the [selector syntax](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) which means appending a `#` to the id. So, change

```
 $(id).fadeIn();
```

to

```
 $("#" + id).fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function shoh(id) { 
    var el = $('#' + id);
    if (el.is(':visible')) {
        el.hide();
    } else {
        el.fadeIn();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due jquery works for you, you won't write crossbrowser code.

So simply

```
var $el = $('#'+id); // <-- this is the main key :-)

if ($el.css('display') == "none"){
        $el.fadeIn();     
} else {
        $el.hide();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just declare it as a variable and then wrap it in a jQuery selector:

```
var $el = $(document.getElementById(id));
// if
$el.fadein();
//else
$el.hide();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HsuRe/1/)